# Nested Div Tags Not Perfectly Aligning Within Each Other

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

In my code I am lining using a pair of div tags, one nested in the other, and I am getting this errant white space between the two that I cannot seem to CSS away in a manner that is acceptable. The white space is variant based on the scale of the page; when I zoom in it shifts and can go away, which makes me believe that this is a ratio issue that I'm unable to solve.

The following image demonstrates the issue

[image: The following image demonstrates the issue]

the following code snippet demonstrates the issue (possibly variable to browser, computer screen, etc)

```css
.container{
    @apply m-2;
    @apply border-main-dark;
    @apply w-full; 
    @apply max-w-xs;
    border: 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.blue-gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #97D6ED 0%, #52BAE2 50%, #0386B7 100%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
      <div class="w-full blue-gradient">
          <h5 class="text-white p-2">Login Form</h5>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks fine in FireFox.

Comment: @disinfor I'm on Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit). as an aside, adjusting margins with negative -0.2px can fix it on the left and top side, not the right for the reason that its pulling the inner div around, setting the display:table; also works but I find both not optimal solutions.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome for me